# Custom selector for visual closeness of elements in a specific direction with jQuery based on rendered location and size

Tags: jquery

I need selectors which are able to retrieve correct results for visual closeness queries like the following:

- `$("h2:closestTo('div#example')");`
- `$("input:below('label:contains(\"Username\")')");`

Closeness and distances should be dependent of the visual location of elements rendered in the web browser (and differs for different window sizes).

Is there any way to do that with jQuery? I think it will involve the usage of [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a first working version by myself.

**Demonstration**: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/L5ZM8/

Definition of **"above"**: Only elements which are visually above a reference element are returned. Also, they have to be in horizontal bounds of the reference elements. The same rules apply to **"below"**, **"leftTo"** and **"rightTo"**.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].above = function(node, stackIndex, properties) {
    return inDirection(node, "above", properties[3]);
};

jQuery.expr[':'].below = function(node, stackIndex, properties) {
    return inDirection(node, "below", properties[3]);
};

jQuery.expr[':'].leftTo = function(node, stackIndex, properties) {
    return inDirection(node, "leftTo", properties[3]);
};

jQuery.expr[':'].rightTo = function(node, stackIndex, properties) {
    return inDirection(node, "rightTo", properties[3]);
};

inDirection = function(node, direction, selector) {
    var topSource = jQuery(selector).offset().top;
    var leftSource = jQuery(selector).offset().left;
    var bottomSource = topSource + jQuery(selector).height();
    var rightSource = leftSource + jQuery(selector).width();

    var topTarget = jQuery(node).offset().top;
    var leftTarget = jQuery(node).offset().left;
    var bottomTarget = topTarget + jQuery(node).height();
    var rightTarget = leftTarget + jQuery(node).width();

    if(direction == "above") {
        return bottomSource > bottomTarget && leftSource <= rightTarget && rightSource >= leftTarget;
    }

    if(direction == "below") {
        return topSource < topTarget && leftSource <= rightTarget && rightSource >= leftTarget;
    }

    if(direction == "leftTo") {
        return rightSource > rightTarget && topSource <= bottomTarget && bottomSource >= topTarget;
    }

    if(direction == "rightTo") {
        return leftSource < leftTarget && topSource <= bottomTarget && bottomSource >= topTarget;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Use the selector like in the following examples. The argument to the custom selector has to be a selector which returns exactly one element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    elementsAbove = jQuery("div:above('#footer')");
    elementsBelow = jQuery("div:below('#header')");
    elementsLeftTo = jQuery("div:leftTo('#sidebar-right')");
    elementsRightTo = jQuery("div:rightTo('#sidebar-left')");
}
```

Please tell me if that works for you and/or you have suggestions to make it better.

Comment: Congrats, Seems to work just fine. One way to improve it is to have it handle wide range selectors in the argument. right now it'll only work for a single match.

Comment: How should that work? Should the reference elements ALL be in the left/right/top/bottom or just one of them?

Comment: probably just one of them, dunno if there is any use for that, but just a pointer for optional support.

Comment: also it would be cool to specify a minimum and/or maximum distance, maybe as another custom selector

Comment: I couldn't find any way to sort using selectors so the `closest` selector might prove difficult to implement.

Comment: this is indeed also an important task

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom selectors to do it ([read here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html)).

`offset` is indeed the way to go to do it. it should be a very interesting (though probably inefficient) selector to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way using selectors to perform sorting, implementation of `closest` or of a `below` with closest result can only be achieved using extending jQuery with a method.

Something like:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  closestTo: function(sourceElement) {
    var closestObj = null, closestDist = Math.pow(2, 31);
    this.each(function() { 
       var distToTarget = calcDist(this,sourceElement);
       if (distToTarget < closestDist) {
          closestObj = this;
          closestDist = distToTarget;
       } 
    });
    return closestObj;
  },
  below: function(sourceElement) {
    .....
  }
});

function calcDist(source,target) {...}
```

you invoke it using:

```
$("h2").closestTo('div#example');
```

#### Update: Same method with sorting:

```
closestTo: function(sourceElement) {
        var targets = this;
        targets.each(function() { 
           $(this).data('distToSource',calcDist(this,sourceElement));
        });
        targets.sort(function(a, b) {
          var compA = $(a).data('distToSource');
          var compB = $(b).data('distToSource');
          return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
         });
        return targets;
      }
```

didn't try it but it should work. (perhaps you'd need to switch `a` and `b` in the sorting function, didn't think it through)

Comment: nice start, but how can we get a sorted list of all matching elements with closestTo, not only the closest one?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably a bit late for what you were trying to do now, but I liked the idea you proposed in your question, and decided that I would start writing a jQuery plugin to do something like this when I got a bit of free time. I have now been able to spend a (small) bit of time on this, and you can see the results [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FHqrC/4/).

You can call the plugin as follows:

```
$("#bottom").physicallyClosest("div").css("background-color", "#ffff00");
```

The above example will change the background colour of the `div` closest to the element with `id` "bottom".

The plugin can take several options:

`reverse` (boolean) - if `true`, it finds the furthest element rather than the closest
`excludeChildren` (boolean) - if `true` it ignores elements that are direct children of the target element
`excludeDescendants` (boolean) - if `true` it ignores all descendant elements of the target element

I won't post the entire code here, because it would be pointless, but you can see it in the fiddle. As mentioned, this is the result of very little work, so I'm sure there are bugs!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I think we should be able to collaboratively create a nice jquery plugin with lots of useful features. But i think we need another platform than Stackoverflow for that. We can post our results here though.